# Laravel: Auth Midleware returns 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: laravel, api, authentication, routes, middleware

I have an issue with authenticating a user. This is the Authentication method in my controller:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){
    $user = User::where('username', $request->username)->first();
    $user_model = new User;
    $return_credentials = [
      'message' => "User does not exist.",
      'status' => false,
      'user_details' => ""
    ];

    if(!empty($user) && !is_null($user)){
      $remember = Str::random(60);

      if(\Auth::attempt(['username' => $request->username, 'password' => $request->password, 'verified' => '1'], $remember)){
        $user = \Auth::user();
        $token_result =  $user->createToken('Personal Access Token'); 
        $token = $token_result->token;
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);

        $return_credentials['message'] = "User Successfully Logged in.";
        $return_credentials['status'] = true;

        $token->save();
      }else{
        $return_credentials['message'] = "User Failed to Log in.";
        $return_credentials['status'] = false;
      }
    }

    $return_credentials['user_details'] = $user;

    return response()->json($return_credentials);
}
```

Every time I access a route using(this middleware):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::get('user', '\App\Http\Controllers\UserController@verifyUserLoggedIn');  
});
```

It returns:
`GET http://..../api/auth/user 401 (Unauthorized)`

Q: Am I missing a step or anything?

Comment: you are using 2 different guards here btw

Comment: May I know what you mean? Like, which is which?

Comment: your default guard is probably `'web'` so `Auth::attempt(...)` is using the `'web'` guard ... then you are using the auth middleware to check the `'api'` guard, which is a different mechanism for authentication

Answer (score 0):

Add `auth:api` in your `app\Http\kernel.php` :

```
'api' => [
           'throttle:60,1',
           'bindings',
           'auth:api',
        ],
```